# How to use a Wildcard SSL with WordPress Network?

Tags: multisite, ssl

I am using WordPress Network to have a network of sites, but as each site needs to be on Facebook they now need to be SSL secured. (*Note: not just the admin, but the whole front-facing site*)

I purchased a wildcard SSL certificate for the whole domain, and am using subdomains on the site site.example.com

Does anybody have simple steps for achieving this, as I have tried searching Google and not been very successful. Visiting https://site.example.com does not show the blog, instead it shows the server default page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I did this recently for a client.  A lot of it will depend on your host, though.

Most hosts are set up to only listen for traffic on port 80.  SSL requires that Apache listen on port 443.  You're seeing the default server page likely because Apache isn't set up to forward traffic for those subdomains.

You need to contact your host and make sure that traffic for https://site.example.com is pointed to the same directory as http://site.example.com.  If you're using WordPress Multisite with *subdomains* this should be easy enough to set up.  Each subdomain should have its own folder on the server ... it's just a matter of making the server point traffic for the SSL version to the same location as the non-SSL version.

If, however, you're using WordPress Multisite with *subdirectories* and mapping subdomains to those subdirectories (which is what my client was doing) you're out of luck.  Shared hosts aren't set up to allow SSL mapping that way because it requires specific `VirtualHost` declarations in Apache.

This is the problem my client faced - traffic to https://site.example.com was redirected to https://example.com because Apache couldn't handle it.

Answer (score 0):

The only config to worry about with WordPress end is enabling/forcing SSL/HTTPS connections which can be done in the WordPress config file.

some information on this here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL

Setting up the SSL cert is something your web host will need to setup for you. If you are self hosting then this question would be better asked at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: That just says "administration over SSL", I want the whole site to be secured (as it is for Facebook which requires iFrames to be secured).

Comment: Just force https:// on your entire website. This can be done with your .htaccess file. Here is a starting point http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/force-ssl-htaccess.html but you will need to modify for it to work with all subdomains.

Comment: Also there is a number of plugins to force SSL: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-https/screenshots/